# Can pandoc markdown convert XML to a HTML or LaTex table?

Tags: html, xml, googletest, pandoc

I am using Google Test to [generate an XML Report](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Generating_an_XML_Report). I am also using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) to write my reports.

Is it possible to use [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) to convert the XML Google Test report into an HTML file where the XML elements are represented in nice tables automagically?

Here is the example of the XML report of a failing test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="8" failures="1" disabled="0" errors="0" timestamp="2015-05-29T11:40:56" time="0.018" name="AllTests">
  <testsuite name="orientPoints" tests="8" failures="1" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0.018">
    <testcase name="trianglePolygon" status="run" time="0" classname="orientPoints" />
    <testcase name="regularOctogon" status="run" time="0" classname="orientPoints" />
    <testcase name="orientRegularOctogon" status="run" time="0" classname="orientPoints" />
    <testcase name="square" status="run" time="0" classname="orientPoints" />
    <testcase name="rectangleDuplicateEdges" status="run" time="0" classname="orientPoints" />
    <testcase name="orientationBug" status="run" time="0" classname="orientPoints" />
    <testcase name="randomCirclePointsOrientedByProjection" status="run" time="0.018" classname="orientPoints" />
    <testcase name="uniqueSquareWithDuplicatePoints" status="run" time="0" classname="orientPoints">
      <failure message="geomTestOrient.C:425&#x0A;Value of: pointChainIsOriented( squareOriented.begin(), squareOriented.end(), squareNormal )&#x0A;  Actual: false&#x0A;Expected: true" type=""><![CDATA[geomTestOrient.C:425
Value of: pointChainIsOriented( squareOriented.begin(), squareOriented.end(), squareNormal )
  Actual: false
Expected: true]]></failure>
      <failure message="geomTestOrient.C:443&#x0A;Value of: squareOriented.size() == 4&#x0A;  Actual: false&#x0A;Expected: true&#x0A;failed iteration : 0&#x0A;square size : 14&#x0A;oriented unique square size : 6&#x0A;input front : (-5.9729471176018073e-16 1.0000000000000007 6.1131855418087139e-16)&#x0A;input back : (1.0000000000000004 0.99999999999999933 5.2878054241263088e-16)&#x0A;" type=""><![CDATA[geomTestOrient.C:443
Value of: squareOriented.size() == 4
  Actual: false
Expected: true
failed iteration : 0
square size : 14
oriented unique square size : 6
input front : (-5.9729471176018073e-16 1.0000000000000007 6.1131855418087139e-16)
input back : (1.0000000000000004 0.99999999999999933 5.2878054241263088e-16)
]]></failure>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Comment: Did you achieve anything here? I doubt it works out of the box, since there is no way for pandoc to know how you'd like e.g. a `testcase` to be rendered. You could probably use an xml-parser (e.g. via [tag:python]) to convert it by yourself, or maybe [tag:XSLT] somehow helps...

Comment: As Tobias mentioned, it would be better to create your [xslt](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp) and then feed the html output to pandoc to generate reports.